# function of a function

Tags: function-construction

I have the following two functions, 'f' and 's':

```
ClearAll[f, s, num, a, b, b1, b2, n]
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;

f[num_Integer, a_Integer, b_] := 
  Sum[1/2 (1 + (-1)^(d - a))*b^(
    2*d)/((num - d)! (d - a)!! (d + a + 3)!!), {d, a, num}];
s[num_Integer, n_Integer, a_Integer, b1_, b2_] := 
  f[num - n, a, b1*b2]/(f[num, a, b1]*f[num, a, b2])^(1/2);
```

I want mathematica to evaluate the functions 'f' and 's' analytically for general parameters. When I then type:

```
f[5, 0, 0]
f[3, 0, 0]
s[5, 2, 0, 0, 0]
FullSimplify[f[n, a, b]]
FullSimplify[s[num, n, a, b1, b2]]
```

I get the following output:

1/360

1/18

20

f[n, a, b]

s[num, n, a, b1, b2]

The first three results are correct (all 5 results remained the same when defining 'f' and/or 's' using Set rather than SetDelayed). However I want mathematica to evaluate 'f' and 's' with generic parameters n, a, b, b1, b2, and this does not occur in the last two lines. Why?

Comment: "with generic parameters" - but since you restricted `f` and `s` to evaluate only for integer arguments, it will remain unevaluated if you do not give it integer arguments.

Comment: Okay, can you post an answer to your question, please?

Comment: I guess its too late now..